# SQL-Server: Create table with integer as id (primary key), but without autoid/autoincrement?

Tags: sql, multithreading, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Question:

In SQL-Server, is it possible to have an integer (not a GUID) as ID (primary key), but **without using AutoID/AutoIncrement**, so that I can set the ID manually when I have to, without getting into trouble in a multithreaded environment (web application) ?

If so, if i have to inserts two+ rows after another, and they primary keys are not given, how do I have to design the function that generates the ID for insert so that it is thread-safe and I don't get the same id for 2+ inserts/records ?

Comment: Whilst it is perfectly possible to have a PK that's not an identity,  you've then described a situation in which identity sounds ideal - is there a reason you can't use it?

Comment: @Bridge: Right now, I need to delete and re-import the user table periodically. If somebody inserts a new user after I deleted it, it should assign a new id with the next highest value, if I re-import the old users, it should reassign the same ID to the same user. Right now, I have to switch identity insert off/on, and then it breaks the insertion of a new user in the web application during the time that identity insert is switched.

Comment: @Quandary - actually, you have to turn identity insert *on* (The sense of the setting is "I'm going to insert an identity value") - and it only affects the connection on which the option is set - it shouldn't affect other connections from e.g. the web application.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't *delete* the user-table, but update existing users during the import. "INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" may be of help here. Although, apparently you're using two different sources to get user-information from (import and direct insert). If both rely on an 'autonumber' ID, results will be unpredictable. Maybe consider constructing a primary key from the actual data (for example 'username')

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whey you cannot use an incremental identity for this, but you COULD simulate the unique key with a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER.

```
PRINT CONVERT( BIGINT, CONVERT( VARBINARY, NEWID() ) )
```

Basically, this shows you how to convert a uniqueidentifier (`NEWID()`)to a bigint. Thus you will be able to achieve your desired outcome but putting that into a function.

Comment: Since `GUID` is 16 byte and `BIGINT` is 8 byte then you will have collision.

Comment: hmm.. you are right!  and after some thought, hey, why can't you use UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?  You can get the desire outcome.

Comment: @Joseph: Because there is already data in 100's of tables where that  integer is referenced.